# Каков алгоритм работы Java.math.sin?

Tags: кэширование, java

И не быстрее ли будет его заменить статичной таблицей (массивом `float[90000]`) значений этой функции на интервале [`0;90` градусов], если в приложении много тригонометрических операций, в которых не нужна точность больше чем два знака после запятой.  При этом всю остальную тригонометрию переопределить через новую реализацию `sin`. Такая таблица займет 4 (размерность `float`) * 90 * 1000 (три знака после запятой) ~ 300кБайт в памяти. Стоит ли оно того? Какие еще могут быть подводные камни при таком подходе?

Comment: А где, ради интереса, вы уперлись в производительность синуса? :)

Comment: я не упирался, но заранее обдумываю, там уже 30 realtime вызовов  тригонометрии накопилось за один проход отрисовки кадра, ничем хорошим это точно не кончится

Comment: изменений в коде на 15 минут. Можно собрать статистику погрешности вычислений на случайных значениях, если в пределах нормы - не вижу проблем

Comment: @igumnov, а Вы померьте, быстрее будет. Заодно результат опубликуйте здесь.

Comment: @avp, да так и сделаю скорее всего, позже опубликую там еще без этого много работы.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Лично мне кажется, что упереться в производительность синуса можно только при наличии **огромного** числа вычислений, то есть при каких-либо инженерных расчетах. В таком случае точность обычно очень существенна, а значит подход с кэшированием значений синуса *оказывается непрактичным.*
- В этом случае намного более предпочтительным смотрится вариант с вынесением вычислений в `native` модуль, где, например, [**будет использоваться `SIMD.`**](http://gruntthepeon.free.fr/ssemath/)

> Потенциально можно также выносить подсчеты такого рода на `GPU,` что должно быть на порядок лучше предлагаемого трюка с кэшированием.

- Сложно быть уверенным, что `JIT` сгенерит хороший код для предлагаемой оптимизации. В таких вещах имеет смысл думать о вопросах следующего типа:

> - Как таблица с предрасчетами уложится в кэше процессора?
> - Какой ассемблерный код будет сгенерен для каждого вызова функции?

- Задумываться о таких вещах, имея толстенную прослойку из `JIT` и байткода чрезвычайно сложно, поскольку `Java` сама по себе **не предназначена для микрооптимизаций.**
- Вот, кстати, еще интересные дискуссии по теме:

> - **https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5005861**
> - **https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4857011**

---

- **(Update)** Раз речь идет о `gamedev'e`, то сам бог велел выносить тяжелые вычисления в шейдера.

Comment: таки да, метод является native и написан либо на С либо на Ассемблере. Как вариант - написать свою реализацию и сравнить быстродействие, но я не думаю что такие вещи писали профаны.

Answer (score 8):

Как человек причастный к вычметодам скажу так:

1. Матфункции в Java реализуются не на чистой Java, а вызовом нативных (сишных) функций. Достаточно посмотреть на исходники Java, там все четко видно: [пруфлинк](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/StrictMath.java.html)
2. В нативной части, реализация `sin/cos` зависит от платформы. Для процессоров семейства x86 реализуется на ассемблере вызовом функции `fsin/fcos`, встроенных в процессор с плавающей точкой.
3. Для прочих процессоров Sun применяет (вернее теперь уже Oracle) широко известную в узких кругах вычислителей библиотеку [FDLIBM](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/)
4. Собственно сам [исходник синуса](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/k_sin.c) показывает, что там какие-то степенные полиномы 13-й степени.

Да, и собственно ответ на вопрос автора: заменить синус будет не быстрее :)

Comment: Классный ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Не буду бабой Вангой, если скажу что он там реализован через разложение в ряд тейлора. И если ребята из Sun очень постарались, то заменили коеффициенты разложения ряда тейлора на минимаксные по Чебышеву.

Если же тебе нужно считать углы с малой точностью (2 знака как ты написал), то тогда лучше это делать через вот этот алгоритм: [CORDIC](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC).

Comment: Вы удивитесь если узнаете, что ряд Тейлора в выч.методах практически не используется в силу своего неудобства, поскольку он дает только аппроксимацию около конкретной точки, а не во всем диапазоне

Comment: Я не удивлюсь, но он там часто используется. Если не верите, мне гляньте исходники хотя бы тойже GLIBC. Правда для хорошо спроектированных библиотек для полиномов ищутся коэффициенты по минимаксу Чебышева, чтобы равномерно размазать погрешность по всему выбранному дианазону. Для sin это [-Pi/4;Pi/4].

Там где используется ряд Тейлора, там применяют range reduction, чтобы минимизировать ошибку аппроксамиции вблизи выбранной точки. Тогда зная отклонение, не трудно посчитать максимальную степень полинома и считать его по параллельному алгоритму типа Estrin's scheme.

Comment: Чтобы не быть голословным вот хорошая ссылка по вычислительным методам. http://www.research.scea.com/gdc2003/fast-math-functions.html

Там подробно обсуждяются как раз проблемы нахождения значений элементарных функции и их разложения в ряд тейлора и нахождение минимаксных полиномов. А также различные схемы сужения интервала и параллельного вычисления значений. Отличное пособие для тех кто решил работать в этой теме. Сам оттуда дергаю идеи когда нужно написать что-то быстрое и с нужной точностью. А вообще все засисит от задачи и того как лучше реализовать на железе. Универсальных схем пока нет

Comment: @JackBlack ну я бы не сказал, что GLIBC это хорошая реализация вычметодов - это все на любительском уровне, так что нерелевантно. Касаемо Чебышева - да тут вы правы: Чебышев идеально подходит для вычметодов (как никак русская школа).

P.S. Ответ немного с опозданием :)